# Generic name for the smallest unit of currency?

Tags: currency, terminology, billing, coins

For example, in Canada and the US, it's a "cent", in Bitcoin it's the "satoshi", in Bahrain it's the "fil".

What's a generic word that means "smallest unit of this currency"? By "smallest" I mean like the smallest amount that you would see in your bank account, or could transfer to someone. Canada got rid of the penny, but our smallest unit is still the cent.

Comment: The mill (one thousandth) is still used in some contexts in the US, most frequently the cost per gallon of gasoline.  Not that anyone calls it that -- we'd say, e.g., "two dollars, eighty-nine and nine-tenths cents" -- but legally it is there.  (Also used in property taxes and some other things.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yeah, but your total is still rounded to a whole cent.

Comment: [ISO 4217 calls it 'minor' unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Treatment_of_minor_currency_units_.28the_.22exponent.22.29)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is [*fractional monetary unit*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fractional+monetary+unit).

[*Monetary unit*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/monetary+unit) refers to the standard base unit of currency, such as the dollar.  The *fractional monetary unit* is a unit of currency that is a subdivision of the basic monetary unit.

Comment: "Fractional" sounds kind of ambiguous because it could refer to any fraction but based on that definition it looks correct.